# SWT Make Composite fully fill parent

Tags: java, swt

I have a problem with my `SWT` GUI:
I have a `TabFolder` in that contains a `ScrolledComposite` that itself holds a `Composite` that in turn holds a few more `Composites`. The problem is that these `Composites` do not fully take the size of the `Composite` on the `ScrolledComposite`.

[image: The problem]
As you can see the inner `Composite` that has the border does not fill it's parent completely.
The parent uses a `GridLayout` therefore I'm already trying to get what I want via setting the `GridData`

```
Composite base = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
base.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

But as you can see this doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to do this?
(At the time of creation I don't now the final size of the parent therefore I can't just do `base.setSize(parent.getSize())`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
layout.marginHeight = 0;
layout.marginWidth = 0;
yourComposite.setLayout(layout);
```

To get rid of margins that you don't want.

---

You might need to apply this to more than one of the parents.